# Adding active class to current page in nav with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, nav

I'm trying to add the 'active' class to the current page's nav link in the header. I made some progress, but I'm running into a small bug, and would appreciate some help. I know the answer is quite obvious, however, I'm new to jQuery/Javascript and I'm having trouble finding it on my own.

Here's my nav HTML structure:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark fixed-top" id="nav">
      <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a href="/" class="nav-link">Me</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="/work">Work</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="/play">Play</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="/contact">Contact</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
</nav>
```

Simple enough. Here's the jQuery code:

```
$(function() {
  $('nav li a[href^="/' + location.pathname.split("/")[1] + '"]').addClass('active');
});
```

The code works on inner pages, however, I'm running into an issue wherein on the home page ('Me', href="/"), the code is adding the active class to all of the nav links.

I think the problem would be solved if I used href="/work/" (added a / to the end of all links), however, when I do that, the links no longer work, because the site then tries to go to www.sitename.com/work/.php.

This is either a simple .htaccess or jQuery fix, however I'm not sure which one, or how to implement it.

Thanks!

Comment: What are you using for your backend? Might be easier add the class from the backend on page load.

Comment: Not sure why you thought this might be a `.htaccess` fix?

Answer (score 5):

A simpler approach is compare the `href` property of link to page url

```
$('nav li a').filter(function(){
  return this.href === location.href;
}).addClass('active');
```

Although the href *attribute* only contains a path, the href *property* in the DOM  contains the full url

Comment: `location.href` return the full url, for example `https://stackoverflow.com/questions` but him need the relative url `/questions`....

Comment: @kip read my comment at bottom of the answer. Can prove it right in this page with `console.log($('#nav-questions').prop('href'))`. The *Questions* link at top only has relative url in attribute

Comment: Great.. It works

Answer (score 3):

That's happening because you are using the ^= selector. 
That means 'startWith' so since all urls start with '/' the 'active' class is being added to all of them.

Replace it with the equal selector and it should work.

```
$('nav li a[href="/' + location.pathname.split("/")[1] + '"]').addClass('active');
```

Comment: I would appreciate a +1 if it helps you :P

Comment: "Thanks for the feedback! Votes cast by those with less than 15 reputation are recorded, but do not change the publicly displayed post score."