# Sharepoint+Jquery, Adding active class to navigation when on that page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, sharepoint

So my HTML looks like so and I've already loaded jQuery to the site, it's jQuery v3.3.1

Now the problem is that I can't show which site the user is on by adding active tag to HTML.
I'm resorting to making my own menu instead of using the sharepoint one because

1. sharepoint is awful to customize
2. the OOTB navbar doesn't allow more than 1 level of dropdown menus.

I've seen other people accomplish adding the active class with jQuery but so far copying their work has not worked for me :P Could someone give me some ideas on how to do this with jQuery?

(It's been 3 years since I've worked with jQuery)

```
<div id='cssmenu'>
<ul>
   <li><a href='/sites/intra/products'><span>Products</span></a></li>
   <li><a href='/sites/intra/marketing'><span>Marketing</span></a></li>
   <li><a href='/sites/intra/sales'><span>Sales</span></a></li>
   <li><a href='/sites/intra/operations'><span>Operations</span></a></li>
   <li><a href='/sites/intra/it'><span>IT</span></a></li>
   <li class='last'><a href='/sites/intra/management'><span>Management</span></a></li>
</ul>
</div>
```

Comment: I've looked at this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14607480/jquery-add-active-class-to-main-menu
and this at least: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47115880/adding-active-class-to-current-page-in-nav-with-jquery

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can feel your pain customizing and working with `SharePoint`. You don't mention where your `HTML` is located. I assume you have already added the `ul`/navigation to your page by adjusting its master page (or another way).

First of all, before manipulating the `DOM` you have to wait until the site has loaded. That's why we wrap the following inside the [`$(document).ready()`](https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/) function.

Within this function, you need to locate the corresponding anchor element to highlight. The `a` tag. You can achieve that with the following `jQuery` [ID, child, and attribute selector](https://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/) as shown below.

```
$(function() {
    $('#cssmenu > ul > li > a[href="' + location.pathname + '"]').addClass('active');
});
```

It is important that the [`location.pathname`](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_loc_pathname.asp) of your current page matches with the `href` provided in one of your `a` elements. Otherwise `jQuery` cannot locate the element and ends up nothing being highlighted. A caveat could be the `SitePages/Home.aspx` suffix `SharePoint` automatically appends. In this case you would need to split the `location.pathname` so that it matches again **or** change the provided `href` to e.g. `/sites/intra/products/SitePages/Home.aspx`.

You can find a working [`jsfiddle` here](https://jsfiddle.net/sfs2hn6q/2/). Hit the `run` button to highlight the corresponding element in the navigation.

Comment: Thank you so much! I'll post below, I still have 1 minor thing I could use some help with :)

Answer (score 0):

So I got almost everything fixed now thanks to you Yannic!

Here is what my JS looks like now:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$( document ).ready(function() {
console.log( "ready!" );
var pathname = window.location.pathname.split( '/' );
var site_root = pathname[1];
var site_name = pathname[2];
var site_page = pathname[3];
$('#pathname').text(location.pathname);
$('#cssmenu ul li a[href="' + '/' + site_root + '/' + site_name + '/' + site_page +'"]').addClass('active');
<!--    alert( '/' + site_root + '/' + site_name + '/' + site_page ); -->
});
</script>
```

Here is the HTML:

```
<div id='cssmenu'>
<ul>
<li><a href='/sites/intra'><span>Intra</span></a></li>
<li class='has-sub'><a href='/sites/intra/hr'><span>HR</span></a>

</li>
 <li><a href='/sites/intra/products'><span>Products</span></a></li>
<li><a href='/sites/intra/marketing'><span>Marketing</span></a></li>

</div>
```

The last issue I would like to ask about is that as you can see I split the pathname into three parts so the HR site is now recognized if the URL is for example www.mysharepoint.com/sites/intra/hr/staff/random_docs.

But I had to use the 3 first pathnames to make it work. The intra homepage however is only /sites/intra. I can't use the third pathname for intra homepage because the third is /SitePages. And if I use that url in the HTML then it takes you to intra Site Pages and not the homepage.

This is very minor and I am very grateful for your help already! So if you don't know an easy and elegant solution then I will just create a new sub-site called Home or something like that and use that instead.

I hope this post helps others who might struggle with the same problem.(In the JS there is the console.log and then an alert, these I only used to check my sanity :P, they can be removed)